# No projects support the 'serve' target. Stuck and can't run Angular project on my localhost

Tags: angularjs

I've tried to fork an angular project from GitHub, and run it with ng serve. But I get the error "No project support the 'serve' target". I'm really stuck and don't know what to do. I'm new to Angular, does anyone know what to do? My intent would be that of running the project on my localhost so I can see how the code functions. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance

Comment: Please check the project's angular.json file and make sure that your angular-cli version matches with the forked project's cli version.

Comment: What's the project you're forking? It's hard to help without code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

then

```
npm start
```